# Question about using N-channel MOSFETs in a current sharing controller

Tags: power-supply, power, transistors, mosfet

My question is specifically regarding LTC4353 :

> Product link: http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4353
>
> Datasheet link: http://www.linear.com/docs/41582

Looking at the diagram on the product link, or the first page of the datasheet, I noticed that it is using an N-channel MOSFET, but the current direction is labelled as from Source to Drain.

I'm wondering what is the reasoning behind this implementation? Is it done to make use of the body diode of the MOSFET?

Comment: The title of this Q does not match the body of the Q.

Answer (score 1):

It is an application called ideal diode. When the IC detects that the body diode of the MOSFET is conducting, it turns on the MOSFET to lower the conduction losses and minimize forward voltage. MOSFETs are unipolar devices and they can conduct current both ways.

Comment: You mean bipolar? to be able to conduct current both ways.

Comment: No, they are unipolar because they are either p or n doped. Bipolar transistors, like NPN or PNP contain both p and n doping.

Comment: It may be more fair to say that they are unipolar when they are not in the 'on' state. When a conduction channel is present, polarity is irrelevant since there is no impediment to current flow in either direction.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the circuit function, you don't want the drooping external rail to drag down the internal OR'd rail.  So if say Vin1 drops to ground with Vin2 at 15V and the MOSFET's were the other way around you'd simply short out the rail through the body diode of NMOS 1.